# Python regex not matching full capture group

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a Python script to add some IRC logs (energymech format) into a database; to do this I have to split the strings into their parts (timestamp, user, message).

I'm using the following regex to get the lines of text which fit:

`normalline = re.compile('^\[[^\]]*(\d{2}):\d+:\d+\] <([^>]+)> (.*)$')`

The problem is that it doesn't correctly assign the first capture group (it only returns the first 2 characters in the group).

The line of text I'm testing it against it `[20:33:02] <user> random message here`

The script I'm using to test is the following:

```
import re
normalline = re.compile('^\[[^\]]*(\d{2}):\d+:\d+\] <([^>]+)> (.*)$')
print normalline.search('[20:33:02] <user> random message here').groups()
```

The result I get is `('20', 'user', 'random message here')` instead of `('20:33:02', 'user', 'random message here')`

I'm sure that I'm messing the regex somehow but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Comment: Something with your first group `^\[[^\]]*(\d{2}:\d+:\d+)\] <([^>]+)> (.*)$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you only need to change the first capture group to encapsulate all three numbers:

```
^\[[^\]]*(\d{2}:\d+:\d+)\] <([^>]+)> (.*)$
```

This matches:

```
('20:33:02', 'user', 'random message here')
```

You might also want to limit the second and third number to only two digits, like you have for the first number:

```
^\[[^\]]*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] <([^>]+)> (.*)$
```